# Include in-kernel firmware blobs in kernel binary

Tags: linux-kernel, firmware

I am compiling my own kernel (4.4.x) on Debian Stretch, and I want to include the firmware for my radeon graphics card in the kernel, so that it does not need to be loaded from userspace.

```
CONFIG_FIRMWARE_IN_KERNEL
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE
```

I have installed the firmware files to `/lib/firmware/`

```
apt-get install firmware-amd-graphics
```

How can I find out which firmware files I need to include for my specific graphis card?

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland GL [FirePro W2100]
```

I assume I will need some of the following firmware files:

```
/lib/firmware/radeon/oland_*.bin
```

but which ones ?

In general, what is the process of finding out which firmware files a particular hw/driver needs ?

Answer (score 5):

Gentoo wiki [radeon article](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Radeon#Built-in_kernel) describes how to include firmware into your kernel binary. The article also includes a table listing firmware binaries required for each GPU model. For your *FirePro W2100* ([Oland chipset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#FirePro_Workstation_Series_.28Wx100.29)) the table lists following firmware binaries:

```
radeon/oland_ce.bin radeon/oland_mc.bin radeon/oland_me.bin
radeon/oland_pfp.bin radeon/oland_rlc.bin radeon/oland_smc.bin 
radeon/TAHITI_uvd.bin
```

Examining kernel log using `dmesg| grep "direct-loading firmware"` on your system should tell which firmware was loaded automatically:

```
radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/OLAND_pfp.bin
radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/OLAND_me.bin
radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/OLAND_ce.bin
radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/OLAND_rlc.bin
radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/OLAND_mc2.bin
radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/OLAND_smc.bin
radeon 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware radeon/TAHITI_uvd.bin
```

I imagine this method was used to gather the data used for the tables in gentoo wiki.

Firmware to be included in kernel image during build is configured using [`CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/firmware/built-in-fw.html) option. The directory from where the build system looks for the extra firmware is configured using `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR` option.

**How to include firmware binary, in steps:**

1. You need to build the radon driver (and Direct Rendering Manager) directly into kernel, not as a module. Module would need to be loaded from filesystem.
2. Configure `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR` to [`/lib/firmware`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/firmware-amd-graphics/filelist), the location distribution installs binaries images to. This way you do not need to copy the firmware binaries around.
3. List the firmware files in `CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE`, multiple files separated by space.

**Using *menuconfig*:**

1. Build radeon driver directly to kernel.

   ```
   Device Drivers  --->
       Graphics support  --->
           <*> Direct Rendering Manager (XFree86 4.1.0 and higher DRI support)  --->
           <*> AMD GPU
   ```
2. Include the firmware

   ```
   Device Drivers  --->
       Generic Driver Options  --->
           [*] Include in-kernel firmware blobs in kernel binary
               (radeon/... radeon/...)
               (/lib/firmware) Firmware blobs root directory
   ```

Comment: thanks, that helped. But still did not completly answer my question. What is the process, in general, of finding out which firmware files a particular hw/driver needs ? In other words, how did the gentoo people find which firmware files are needed?

Comment: I imagine the data in gentoo wiki was gathered inspecting the logs. As far as I am able to undestand the source code in kernel, it looks like radeon firmware is loaded using `request_firmware()`, which radeon driver calls from it multiple functions in different files. I haven't found any indication of a list or other summary of required firmware images, instead it looks like the driver requires whatever firmware it needs in the relevant submodules. You probably need to get an answer from a radon driver developer (or someone else familiar with the code) to get a precise description.

Comment: @MartinVegter Just run "modinfo name_of_module" to see which firmware it loaded.